# Is the expectation of log-concave function still log-concave?

Tags: probability, logarithms, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I know the expectation preserves the concavity (or convexity), but I was wondering is it still true that the  expectation of log-concave function still  log-concave; to be more precise,

> Let $g(x,Y)$ be log-concave function in $x$ where $Y$ be discrete-time random variable with density $f_Y$. Is it true that 
>   $$
> E[g(x,Y)]
> $$be still log-concave in $x$?

I noticed there is one result called Prekopa theorem, which states that if $g(x,y): \mathbb{R}^{n+m} \to \mathbb{R}$ be (jointly) log-concave, then
$$
h(x) = \int g(x,y) dy
$$is log-concave. But I'm not sure how to apply properly on the expectation case, since I have to deal with the log-concavity of integrand function $g(x,y) f_Y(y)$ first; i.e.,
$$
E[g(x,Y)] = \int g(x,y) f_Y(y)dy
$$

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily.  Consider $Y$ such that $Pr[Y=0]=Pr[Y=1]=1/2$.  Define $g(x,Y)=e^{Yx}$.  Then $g(x,Y)$ is log concave in $x$ because $\log g(x,Y) = Yx$ is linear.  But: 
$$ E[g(x,Y)] = \frac{1 + e^x}{2} $$
and $\log E[g(x,Y)] = \log(1/2) + \log(1 + e^x)$, which is no longer concave.

Comment: Thanks @Michael !! very helpful example.

Answer (score 1):

It is true under stricter hypothesis.

**Proposition.**
Let $g(x,y)$ be *jointly* log-concave and $Y$ be a log-concave random variable with density $f(y)$. Then $\mathbb{E}[g(x,Y)]$ is log-concave.

*Proof.*
The function $g(x,y)f(y)$ is log-concave because is logarithm $\log g(x+y) + \log f(y)$ is the sum of two concave functions. Therefore, because [log-concavity is preserved under marginalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9kopa%E2%80%93Leindler_inequality#Applications_in_probability_and_statistics),
$$
\mathbb{E}[g(x,Y)] = \int g(x,y)f(y)\,dy
$$
is log-concave.