# Log-concavity of $y\mapsto E[(y+X)^\eta]$

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

I know the function $y\mapsto(y+x)^\eta$ for $x>0$ and $\eta>0$ is log-concave. Is this true of the expectation over a positive R.V. in the following sense,
$$y\mapsto E[(y+X)^\eta]$$
where X is a positive random variable?
Any pointers appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\eta\leq 1$, the function $y\mapsto(y+x)^\eta$ is concave, so $y\mapsto \mathbb{E}[(y+X)^\eta]$ is concave too, therefore it is log-concave.

For $\eta>1$, it is false in general. I give you a counterexample in the case $\eta=2$ because the computations are easier, though it can be generalized. Consider the discrete random variable $X$ whose law is $\frac13(\delta_1+\delta_2+\delta_x)$, with the parameter $x$ to be chosen later. We have
$$
\log\mathbb{E}[(y+X)^2] = \log\left(\frac{(y+1)^2+(y+2)^2+(y+x)^2}3\right).
$$
Its second derivative is
$$
2\frac{-3-12x+x^2-(18+6x)y-9y^2}{\bigl(5+x^2+(6+2x)y+3y^2\bigr)^2},
$$
which evaluated at $y=0$ equals
$$
2\frac{-3-12x+x^2}{(5+x^2)^2}.
$$
For $x$ sufficiently large, this is positive, disproving the concavity of $\log\mathbb{E}[(y+X)^2]$.

You might be interest also in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341700/is-the-expectation-of-log-concave-function-still-log-concave).

**Edit: it is true if $X$ is log-concave.** It follows from [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2991593/180428).

Assume that $X$ has a log-concave density $f(x)$. Then the function
$F(x,y) = (x+y)^\eta f(x)$ is log-concave, because $\log F(x,y) = \eta(x+y) + \log f(x)$ is the sum of an affine and a concave function. Therefore by the fact that [log-concavity is preserved under marginalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9kopa%E2%80%93Leindler_inequality#Applications_in_probability_and_statistics), $\mathbb{E}[(y+X)^\eta] = \int F(x,y)\,dx$ is also log-concave.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then I'll see if there could be some cases where for $\eta>1$, log-concavity is preserved. I am particularly interested in the case where $X$ is inverse-gamma.

Comment: @Seneleh I don't know why I didn't think about it (it was late at night...), but I think i have a complete answer for you. Just check I didn't say something stupid.

Comment: Sounds good, would work for any X that has a log-concave probability density function. Just a typo: the log of $(x+y)^\eta$ is $\eta \log(x+y)$. Thanks a lot @Federico